# How to make request to Checker API using Guzzle?

Tags: php, httprequest, guzzle6

I want to use [checker API](https://docs.checkr.com/) with Guzzle 6, so how can I make the following request using guzzle?

```
$ curl https://api.checkr.com \
        -u YOUR_TEST_API_KEY:
```

I tried the following way but I know its wrong!

```
$res = $client->request('GET', 'https://api.checkr.com', ['-u' => 'MY_TEST_API_KEY']);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on documents its asking you to pass your token as username and empty password. Please try below code. Just replace YOUR_TEST_API_KEY  with right key ;)

```
$res = $client->request('GET', 'https://api.checkr.com', ['auth' => ['YOUR_TEST_API_KEY', null]]);
```

Comment: Thanks It worked now, You need to put another bracket at the end to close the array.